# Rspec Passes Locally, Fails with Travis

Tags: ruby, rspec, nokogiri, travis-ci

rspec passes locally but fails when I run it with Travis CI.

The common denominator to my specs that fail is using :to_xml from nokogiri.

I'm not sure why Travis would have an issue with this - I checked the Travis logs and nokogiri 1.6.6.2 was in fact installed. (I've included require 'spec_helper' in my .spec file.)

Or in general, why would this happen?

Comment: `rspec --version` on both Travis and local machine, compare, check version differences.

Comment: Thank you @набиячлэвэлиь -- both versions are the same though :/

Comment: Hrrrm, remove all relevant downloaded state (if rspec has any) on your local machine, try again. This is likely caused my modifications not in the Git repo.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by:  remove all relevant downloaded state (if rspec has any) on your local machine ?

Comment: I mean: clone a fresh copy of your repo, remove rspec's data (cache, downloaded/built artifacts, etc), and try again. Also consult the "Related" section on the sidebar, maybe some of them will have the same problem you're encountering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". As is we have no idea what is in your spec so any answers are going to be generalized swipes at answering, not detailed answers. Broad/general questions and broad/general answers are not what SO is for, so please add additional information to narrow down the problem.